# After redirecting to another page how to use controller and scope data of previous page in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This is for an assignment. Here table contains book details which contains book name, author, price, ISBN and category. When user click on book name it should redirect to order page displaying book name, author and price.

**BookPage.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="book.js">
    <body ng-app="mymodule" >
    <div ng-controller="myController" >
          <table border=2>
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ISBN</th>
              <th>NAME</th>
              <th>AUTHOR</th>
              <th>CATEGORY</th>
              <th>PRICE</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="book in books">
                <td>{{ book.ISBN }}</td>
                <td ><a href="" ng-click="getdetail(book)">{{ book.Name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ book.Author }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.Category }}</td>
                <td>{{ book.price }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    **books.js**        


 var myapp = angular.module('mymodule', []);
     myapp.controller("myController", function($scope, $http,$window) {
      $http.get("https://api.myjson.com/bins/p4ujn").then(function(response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
            $scope.getdetail=function(){
              $scope.getbookdetail=this.book;
              $window.location.href = "orderpage.html";     
            }
      }); 
    });
```

Page to be redirected when user click on book name.

**orderpage.html**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="book.js"></script>
    <body ng-app="mymodule" >
      <div ng-controller="myController" >
          {{getbookdetail.Name}}<br>
          {{getbookdetail.Author}}
          {{getbookdetail.price }}<br>
        </div>
    </body
```

This is my code. It display nothing, just a blank page.

Comment: There are many ways you can create a getter setter service/factory , pass data in the route or use localStorage module. One other way is to use Parent controller and access data using $scope.$parent

Comment: As i am new to angular js..can you please  elaborate . I dont know exactly how to use that

Comment: Sajeetharan Answer below can help you. This is one way of doing it.
and he is right this is the best way of doing it there are other ways but you should use the way he wrote the code.

Comment: i can write code for you if you want?

Comment: @AsifSaeed: please do not offer to write code for posters here. It is very helpful of you, but we do not want for Stack Overflow to get a reputation as a place where free work can be requested. Arguably a lot of lazy posters area already doing that, and we do not want that situation to get worse.

Comment: (OP noted this was homework in a comment, and asked a reader to finish the work for them, which they later deleted). @user7421580: I do not advocate that you cheat on your homework. Not only is it academic dishonesty, but you are also cheating yourself - what happens if you are asked to make a defence of "your" work and you are unable to? You will realise that you missed a chance to learn something, and your educator may work that out too.

Comment: yes mistake at my end aswell . i shouldn't have posted code here

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should use factory/Services, localStorage, routeParams or Child Parent controllers

Comment: Code only answers have little value here without a proper explanation

Comment: hello @AsifSaeed I tried your code but its not working. after redirecting to orderpage It doesnt have any data in boookdata..

Comment: check this.book got the data or not. do console.log when the click event is fired

Comment: yes.! BookData.add(this.book); contains data which is clicked

Comment: Do some debugging check the methods in factory if data is recieved in the factory add method or not and do check ehwn you get data its sent from the factory get Method

Comment: dataofBooks.get = function(){
        console.log(dataofBooks.books)
    return dataofBooks.books;
};
try this if it still prints undefined?

Comment: Then when you call this in other controller it should return value in other controller :)

Comment: dataofBooks.books contains value wheares console.log(dataofBooks.books) is undefined

Comment: isnt it the same variable?

Comment: yup..same variable

Comment: @AsifSaeed do i need to pass dataobject in get function too?

Comment: Nope for getting data no need to pass any parameters
make sure when this 
$scope.getbookdetail = BookData.get(); function is called in Mycontroller2 data is init

Answer (score 3):

You can use a **[`Service`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)** or **[`factory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)** to share the data across the controllers.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module("clientApp", [])
 app.controller("TestCtrl", 
   function($scope,names) {
     $scope.names =[];
    $scope.save= function(){
      names.add($scope.name);
    }
   
   $scope.getnames = function(){
     $scope.names = names.get();
   }
   }
  );
   
app.factory('names', function(){
  var names = {};

  names.list = [];

  names.add = function(message){
    names.list.push({message});
  };
  
  names.get = function(){
    return names.list;
  };

  return names;
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html >

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="clientApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <button ng-click="save()" > save</button>
    
  </div>
  
  <div ng-init="getnames()" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
     <div  ng-repeat="name in names">
       {{name}}
       </div>
     
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Apart from **`service/factory`** , you can go for other options like **`localStorage`** and **`rootScope`**, but those are not recommended ways.